# AS3, Bullet code

Tags: actionscript

i need some help. I have this code here and it shoots bullets but every time I press the key the bullet will go faster and faster each time.  here is the part I am working on ...

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, kUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);

//character functionality keys//
function kDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
var mainSpeed:int = 5;
    if (event.keyCode == 88){
        gun_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
        BlueBullet_mc.x = gun_mc.x;
        BlueBullet_mc.y = gun_mc.y;
        addChild(BlueBullet_mc);
        BlueBullet_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBlueBullet);
        }
        function moveBlueBullet(e:Event):void{
            e.target.y -=5;
            if (e.target == 0){
                e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBlueBullet);
                removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The bullet is going faster because every time you push the button, you are adding an eventlistener.  So the first time you click it it, it moves -5 px/frame.  The next time, it triggers twice each frame, for -10, then -15 and so on.  To avoid this you either want to remove the eventlistener when the button is pressed, or use a boolean to store whether or not the object is currently moving.